# Xcode UI Test using ErrorTextField from Material Library

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing, cosmicmind

I'm using `ErrorTextField` from *ComicMind's Material library*.

How to access the detail value when using UI Test

if i want to check the detail value in a certain point in the test.

e.g.

```
let userTextField = app.textFields["username"]
XCTAssertEqual(userTextField.detail,"invalid username")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following?

```
userTextField.value as? String
```